# Automaticall add taxonomy in migration

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

I'm trying to get Drupal 6 to automatically add a taxonomy term in a migration. Basically I have

```
// Some code
$this->addFieldMapping('field_supplier', 'source_supplier');
```

In this case, field_supplier is a taxonomy term. What I would like to achieve is for Drupal to check if the value in "source_supplier" is an already existing term, and in that case use that, otherwise it should create a new one and use that.
I tried using

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_supplier:create_term', 'source_supplier');
```

and

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_supplier', 'source_supplier')->arguments(array('create_term' => true));
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!